# ROR rails Unable to add items to booking with start end date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm trying to make a rental application on rails.

I'm stuck on getting the `start_date` and `end_date` to display and then to parse to the `bookings_controller`.

I'm listing the items in an `items_controller` then have an `add_to_cart_controller` to show users' requests.

I would like to parse this to a `bookings_controller` to keep a record of the requests users have made and then items availability.

```
%input{:type =>'text', 
       :placeholder => params[:startdate] != nil ? params[:startdate] : "from date", 
       :id => 'startdate', 
       :name => "startdate", 
       :style => 'width: 100px'}
%input{:type =>'text', 
       :placeholder => params[:startdate] != nil ? params[:enddate] : "to date", 
       :id => 'enddate', 
       :name => "enddate", 
       :style => 'width: 100px'}
```

I've got the application partially working using devise to authenticate and then a user can select the bike and add it to the cart.

I would like to get:

- start and end dates for a user.
- to add a calendar functionality with the start and end date user needs to select.

This should go to a `bookings_controller` which will record all the rentals and update the bikes' availability.

**Carts Controller**

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def add
    # get the ID of the product
    id = params[:id]

    # if the cart is already been created, use the existing cart
    # else create a blank cart
    if session[:cart] then
      cart = session[:cart]
    else
      session[:cart] = {}
      cart = session[:cart]
    end

    # if the product has already been added to the cart, increment the
    # else set the value to 1
    if cart[id] then
      cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
    else
      cart[id] = 1
    end

    # redirect to the cart display page
    redirect_to :action => :index

  end

  def clearCart
    # set the session variable to nil and redirect
    session[:cart] = nil
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end 

  def index
    # if there is a cart, pass it to the page for display
    # else pass an empty value
    if session[:cart] then
      @cart = session[:cart]
    else
      @cart = {}
    end
  end 
end
```

**Items Controller**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :ensure_admin, :only => [:edit, :destroy]
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items Only admin can edit delete items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # GET /items/1
  # GET /items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /items/new
  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  # GET /items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create

    puts "debug +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    puts params.inspect
    puts "debug +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"

    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url, notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def ensure_admin
    unless current_user && current_user.admin?
      render :text => "Access Error Message", :status => :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description, :price, :image_url, :category, :brand)
    end
end
```

**Cart View**

```
<h1>Your Cart</h1>

<% if @cart.empty? %>
    <p>Your Cart is empty</p>
<% end %>

<% total = 0 %>

<table class="cart">
    <tr>
        <td class="legend"></td>
        <td class="legend">Item</td>
        <td class="legend">Price</td>
        <td class="legend">Length</td>
        <td class="legend">Total</td>
    </tr>

<% @cart.each do | id, quantity | %>
    <% item = Item.find_by_id(id) %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="image">
                <%= link_to (image_tag item.image_url, :style => "height:40px"), item %>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="title"><%= link_to item.title, item %></td>
        <td class="price"><%= number_to_currency(item.price) %></td>
        <td class="quantity"><%= quantity %><br /></td>
        <td class="price"><%= number_to_currency(quantity * item.price, :unit => "€") %></td>
            %input{:type =>'text', :placeholder => params[:startdate] != nil ? params[:startdate] : "from date", :id => 'startdate', :name => "startdate", :style => 'width: 100px'}
            %input{:type =>'text', :placeholder => params[:startdate] != nil ? params[:enddate] : "to date", :id => 'enddate', :name => "enddate", :style => 'width: 100px'}
    </tr>
    <% total += quantity * item.price %>
<% end %>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <div class="total">Total:</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="price"><%= number_to_currency(total, :unit => "Eur") %></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>
    <%= link_to 'Make a booking', :controller => :items %>
</p>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :bookings
  get 'bookings/index'
  get 'bookings/show'
  get 'bookings/new'
  get 'bookings/edit'
  get 'bookings/destroy'

  resources :profiles
  get 'bookings/index'
  get 'bookings/show'
  get 'bookings/new'
  get 'bookings/edit'
  get 'bookings/destroy'

  resources :profiles

  devise_for :users
  get '/about' => 'site#about'
  get '/contact' => 'site#contact'
  get '/admin' => 'user#admin_login'
  get '/logout' => 'user#logout'
  get '/cart' => 'cart#index' 
  get '/cart/:id' => 'cart#add'
  get '/cart/clear' => 'cart#clearCart' 
  get '/signedinuserprofile' => 'profiles#signedinuserprofile'
  get '/product' => 'catalog#view'

  resources :items

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'items#index'

  # Example of regular route:
     get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
     get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

end
```

**Model Relations**

***User***

- `has_one :profile`
- `has_many :items`
- `has_many :bookings`

***Profile***

- `belongs_to :user`

***Items***

- `belongs_to :user`
- `has_many :bookings`

***Booking***

- `belongs_to :item`

My key problem is getting the app to accept start and end dates to make a rental booking. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'd also like to know how to display the availability of bikes during booking.

Comment: What do you mean you're 'stuck'? What precisely is not working?

Comment: Can you show what your models look like? What's the relationship between a User, Item, and a Booking?

Comment: Sure, class user has the following  has_one :profile
  has_many :items
  has_many :bookings   Profile belongs_to :user class items:  belongs_to :user
    has_many :bookings last one is class Booking 
  belongs_to :item this might need to be a one to many relationship.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the app to accept start and end dates and make a rental booking.

Comment: So to clarify, you're wanting to give users the ability to rent items by booking an item and accepting start and end dates for the booking? Here's the scenario it sounds like you're trying to achieve, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Scenario:
User A selects item Bike, User A then inputs the start and end dates in a form to create a booking for the Bike.

Comment: Yep exactly. Not sure on the implementation so should the index file have the calendar from the html view and how to pass this start and end date to the controller with the itemid (bike) he or she has selected to record the booking and the make the item unavailable to other users during that period.

Comment: So, with the way you have your relationships set up. I think you will need a method in your Item controller that creates a Booking on the item instance that can have your start and end dates. To get those, you'll need to create a form with the date inputs that submits to that method in the Items controller.

Here's a link to the Rails docs with some view helper methods for creating an input field for dates. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_date